# Windows/IIS response time doubles every 10 days, resets on reboot

Tags: windows, php, iis

I'm running MediaWiki 1.23 on the following machine:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- IIS 7.5
- PHP 5.4.34
- Separate database server with MySQL 5.6.26

I was previously running this setup on a supposedly-identical machine, but since the transition I've seen the response times of wiki pages increase over time. Rebooting the application server brings the response times back into family. Please see the chart below showing the old server in blue (stable response times), and the new server in orange with steadily increasing response times which are reset by rebooting.

[image: the chart below]

Also see the gray line which shows number of hits per day, which is relatively stable (though decreasing slightly probably due to my users not enjoying the slowness).

What could be causing this?

EDIT: The chart above has been updated with the latest data and some annotations.

Comment: are you running low memory when response time increase ? did you tracked response times between Mysql server and your IIS server ?

Comment: We're not running out of memory, and the response times for MySQL queries are not the issue.

Comment: anything special in IIS log that could be different from before and after migration ? the disk on old server and new use the same technologie ? in fact you need an benchmark on old system and the new to compare, cause i ddon't which wiki config could do that (execpt bad rewriting)

Comment: I'm unfortunately not the system administrator, so I don't have direct insight into what is different. By posting here I'm hoping to get some ideas for what to ask the system administrator to check.

Comment: @Froggiz what did you mean when you said "except bad rewriting" in the comment above?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase performance with wiki configuration:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Performance_tuning

this is an exemple with my config

```
# Shared memory settings
$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_ACCEL; #PHP APC
$wgMemCachedServers = array(); 

# Parser Cache
$wgParserCacheExpireTime = 604800; #1 Week

# Load.php expires
$wgResourceLoaderMaxage['versioned']['server'] = 604800;
$wgResourceLoaderMaxage['versioned']['client'] = 604800;
$wgResourceLoaderMaxage['unversioned']['server'] = 604800;
$wgResourceLoaderMaxage['unversioned']['client'] = 604800;

# Job.php rate
$wgJobRunRate = 0;

# Sidebar cache
$wgEnableSidebarCache = true;

# File cache
$wgUseFileCache = true;
$wgFileCacheDirectory  = "$IP/cache";
$wgUseGzip = true;
$wgFileCacheDepth = 0;

# Cache folder
$wgCacheDirectory = "$IP/cache";
```

then you can add some perf with IIS options:

- add expire header
- add cache control
- add output compression

after you did some optimization, you can test it trought google page speed insight :

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights

Comment: These are all good suggestions, but as I said I was on an identical server before and did not have these issues. Well, supposedly it was identical, but clearly something is different.

Comment: i know but at least some infos are there if someone else make a search on wiki perf trouble